# react-select not loading anything

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have the code below. I can see loadOptions are called in the console. I have not found any samples with async function as input, any suggestions why below does not work?

I get following error: "Uncaught TypeError: options.reduce is not a function"

[image]

```
    <AsyncSelect
      cacheOptions
      getOptionLabel={(e) => e.status}
      getOptionValue={(e) => e.id}
      loadOptions={loadAccounts}          
      onChange={(p)=>onAccountChanged(p)}
      onInputChange={(p)=>onAccountInputChanged(p)}
    />


  const loadAccounts = async (inputValue, callback) => {
    // perform a request
    const result = await getMyAccounts();
  
    callback(result)
  }

     const onAccountChanged = (val) => {
      console.log('onAccountChanged'); 
     };

    const onAccountInputChanged = (val) => {
      console.log('onAccountInputChanged'); 
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the result needs to be in specific format. Following solved the problem.

const loadAccounts = async (inputValue) => {
console.log('loadAccounts');
const result = await getMyAccounts();

```
var result2 = result.data.map((film) => ({
  label: film.status,
  value: film.id
}))

console.log(result2); 

return result2;
```

}